# c# Some questions about ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I got some questions about ListViews.

**first question**:
I got 5 listviews made in the designer.
I am trying to make array of 4 listviews (from the 2nd to the last) so I tried this syntax [not inside function]:

```
ListView[] lvs = { listView2, listView3, listView4, listView5 };
```

but it said that the listViews are not static so I tried this syntax (outside function):

```
ListView[] lvs = new ListView[4];
```

and then inside function

```
lvs = { listView2, listView3, listView4, listView5 };
```

but it didnt work too, so finally I used this syntax (outside function):

```
ListView[] lvs = new ListView[4];
```

and this inside function:

```
lvs[0] = listView2;
lvs[1] = listView3;
lvs[2] = listView4;
lvs[3] = listView5;
```

which worked. but I want to do it in one of the previous ways.. can you tell me why it doesnt work for me with the other syntax and how to fix it?

**second question**: I am trying to check if item from listview1 exists in listview2.
so I tried

```
listView2.Items.Contains((ListViewItem)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Clone());
```

but it always return false, even if I do that >

```
listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)listView1.SelectedItems[i].Clone());
```

how can I fix it?, why it always return false? > I DO NOT want to fix it by running loop and check if item = selecteditem.

**third and last question** (which is not related to listviews):
I am using this code

```
((TabPage)tabControl1.Controls["tabPage" + (i + 1)])
```

to convert string to control. the only problem is that I need to tell the control in which control he is, so if I want to convert string to control that located inside a control that located inside other control that located inside other control, the code is too long... is there a better, shorter and easier way to convert string to control (without to write in which control he is)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Individual questions should be separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your third question correctly you might want to use

```
tabControl.Controls.Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)
```

And I also think that there should be separate threads for different questions.

Answer (score 3):

**First question**

You need to insert `new ListView[]`

```
ListView[] lvs = new ListView[] { listView2, listView3, listView4, listView5 };
```

**Second question**
`.Clone()` creates a new object, a new object is never the same as the old one.
You need to find another identifier on the objects to compare.

Comment: It solved my first questiom. about thse second question > I got another identifier for the items to compare - their tag - if both items are the same then their tags should be the same (that is how I made it), but how can I check if item from listview1 exists in listview2 by their tag value without using loop?